# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'score' cannot be null

Tags: laravel, for-loop, textfield, storing-information

**Controller**

```
 public function getScore(Request $request, $id)
{
   // $scores = Criteria::find($id);
    $contestants = Contestant::find($id);
    foreach ($request->criteria as $id => $criteria){
        $criteriaModel = Score::find($id);

        $scores = new Score();
        $scores->judge_name = $request->input('judge_name');
        $scores->contestant =  $contestants->name;
        $scores->criteria = $criteriaModel->criteria;
        $scores->score = $scores->score;
        $scores->save();
    }
    return redirect('/tabulation')->with('status', 'Score saved!');
}
```

**Blade**

```
      @foreach ($criterias as $criteria)
                                       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                           <label for="{{$criteria->name}}">{{$criteria->name}} </br> (0 - {{$criteria->points}})</label>
                                           <input type="text" name="criteria[{{$criteria->id}}][criteria]" value="{{$criteria->name}}" hidden>
                                           <input type="text" name="score[{{$criteria->id}}][score]" class="form-control" placeholder="Input score" required>
                                       </div>
                                   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form field names can contain brackets to store multiple properties for a single name:

```
@foreach ($criterias as $criteria)
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="{{$criteria->name}}">{{$criteria->name}} </br> (0 - {{$criteria->points}})</label>
        <input type="text" name="criterias[{{$criteria->id}}][name]" value="{{$criteria->name}}" hidden>
        <input type="text" name="criterias[{{$criteria->id}}][points]" class="form-control" placeholder="Input score" max="{{$criteria->points}}" name="score" required>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The above form would result the `$request->criterias` variable containing the following value:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "test"
    "points" => "dd"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "tes22t"
    "points" => "sdsd"
  ]
]
```

This value can be used in the controller for creating multiple scores:

```
  foreach ($request->criterias as $id => $criteria){
            $criteriaModel = Criteria::find($id);

            $scores = new Score();
            $scores->judge_name = $request->input('judge_name');
            $scores->contestant =  $contestants->name;
            $scores->criteria = $criteriaModel->name;
            $scores->score = $criteria->points;
            $scores->save();
        }
```

Comment: I can see this now:

array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "criteria" => "Best in Talent"
    "score" => "10"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "criteria" => "Best in Choreography"
    "score" => "15"
  ]
]

But there's an error. Here is the error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'score' cannot be null

Comment: Did you add `score` to `$fillable` in the `Score` model?

Comment: yes I did. In my score table i have fields like, contestant, judge_name, criteria and score. In my criteria table i have, name, category_type and points.

Comment: $contestants = Contestant::find($id);
        foreach ($request->criteria as $id => $criteria){
            $criteriaModel = Score::find($id);

            $scores = new Score();
            $scores->judge_name = $request->input('judge_name');
            $scores->contestant =  $contestants->name;
            $scores->criteria = $criteriaModel->criteria;
            $scores->score = $scores->score;
            $scores->save();
        }

Comment: Is `$criteria->points` filled when you `dd($criteria->points);` it in the controller?

Comment: i changed it to $scores->score; because it says "Trying to get property 'score' of non-object". by the way im not making the points for the criteria i already have it. this is for inputting the score in each criteria. Criteria has points and I made another table which is scores, that is where i would want to place the scores inputted by the judge.

Comment: But i still cant store it

Comment: Is it still giving the column score cannot be null? @ArjayRickziZ.Espina

Comment: Yes it does. I can see this tho:

judge_name 
"User"
contestant 
"Chanix"
criteria 
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "criteria" => "Best in Talent"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "criteria" => "Best in Choreography"
  ]
]
score 
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "score" => "3"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "score" => "1"
  ]
]

Comment: I did update my post. You can check my updated codes :)

Comment: Could you add the updated controller code to the question too? @ArjayRickziZ.Espina

Comment: That is the updated and current controller i am using while having that error. Both controller and my blade codes.

Comment: You are assigning `$scores->score = $scores->score;` to itself, and because `$scores` is a new empty object the value will always be null. Shouldn't the score be filled with the `$criteria` values? @ArjayRickziZ.Espina

Comment: Score is filled with whatever value the judge inputs. Scores for each criteria is different from the points each criteria has.

Comment: But should't this be used: `$scores->score = $criteria->points` instead of `$scores->score = $scores->score;`? @ArjayRickziZ.Espina

Comment: If I change to that, I have this kind of error: Trying to get property 'points' of non-object.

Comment: I wish I could show you my whole files. Sigh. I badly need to solve this for my thesis. This is the only problem I need to solve. Getting the scores from the judge on each contestant and each criteria.

Comment: Could you setup a public/private github repository to share all the files? @ArjayRickziZ.Espina

Comment: I will. I’ll get back to you once it’s available

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change the name of your input to be an array like so:

```
<input type="text" name="criteria[]" value="{{$criterias->name}}" hidden>
```

and in your controller you have to loop through the inputs:

```
foreach ($request->input('criteria') as $criteria){
    $scores = new Score();
    $scores->judge_name = $request->input('judge_name');
    $scores->contestant =  $contestants->name;
    $scores->criteria = $request->input('criteria');
    $scores->score = $request->input('score');
    $scores->save();
}
```

Comment: You are correct. But when I was writing my answer, the other answer was not posted yet. Look at the time.